# I want to find and update a single child of a child using only the key of the table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner in firebase and I'm trying to find a Single ALLOTED child which has value NULL and trying to update it with some value using only location key.Even though I've used limitToFirst(1) all my data where ALLOTTED is NULL is getting updated. I've been racking my brains for quite some while and any help is hugely appreciated. My firebase database:
![][1]

```
   final FirebaseDatabase database =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

   final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("LOCATION/"+s.getSelectedItem().toString());

   Query query = myRef.orderByChild("ALLOTED").equalTo("NULL").limitToLast(1);


            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        slot =childDataSnapshot.getKey();
                        q=""+ myRef.child(slot).child("ALLOTED").setValue(Plateno.getText().toString());
                        w=""+ myRef.child(slot).child("DATE").setValue(sDate);
                        e= ""+myRef.child(slot).child("TIME").setValue(time);
                        r=""+ myRef.child(slot).child("LIMIT").setValue(limit.getSelectedItem().toString());

                        break;
                    }


                    }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO SPACE AVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
                }
    });
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NybnY.png[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used an incorrect listener. Was supposed to use Single event value listener.